# Label in %rep section in NASM

Tags: assembly, preprocessor, nasm

I have `%rep` preprocessor directive which creates a preprocessor loop.
I would like to declare label in it, probably with some concatenation, but  I cannot get the syntax right.

```
%assign i 0 
%rep    64 
   label_%i: ;this, of course, doesn't work
      inc rax    
%assign i i+1 
%endrep
```

So how to force NASM preprocessor to generate `label_i` for every "iteration"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be accomplished by using the `%+` notation.  Here's an excerpt from the documentation:

> 4.1.4 Concatenating Single Line Macro Tokens: %+
>
> Individual tokens in single line macros can be concatenated, to
>   produce longer tokens for later processing. This can be useful if
>   there are several similar macros that perform similar functions.
>
> Please note that a space is required after %+, in order to
>   disambiguate it from the syntax %+1 used in multiline macros.

More information on this and other features in the preprocessor can be found [here](http://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.11.08/html/nasmdoc4.html).

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need to reference the labels from outside the `%rep` block, the within-a-macro local `%%label` syntax can work:

```
%macro  jmpfwd 0
    times 21 nop
    jmp %%fwd                  ;;;;;   <<<------ This jump
    add ax, 0x1234    ; can this stall decoding?
;    lea eax, [ebx+edx+1]
  align 64
  %%fwd:                       ;;;;;   <<<------ jumps here
%endmacro
```

Then use that macro inside a `%rep`

```
    .looptop:
%rep 4
    jmpfwd
%endrep
; times 4 jmpfwd   nope, TIMES only works on (pseudo)instructions, not macros

    dec ecx
    jnz .looptop
```

(Turns out, Skylake [can decode this without LCP stalls every iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29871947/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-data32-data32-nopw-cs0x0rax-rax-1-instruction-i/29872827?noredirect=1#comment77282124_29872827), only a few LCP stalls when the `add` hits the decoders in the same group as `jmp` before branch prediction for the unconditional `jmp` instructions take effect.  The `times 21 nop` prevents it from fitting in the uop cache.)