# Is this a missed optimization in GCC, loading an 16-bit integer value from .rodata instead of an immediate store?

Tags: c, gcc, x86-64, compiler-optimization, micro-optimization

Looking for this code:

```c
#include <stdint.h>

extern struct __attribute__((packed))
{
    uint8_t size;
    uint8_t pad;
    uint16_t sec_num;
    uint16_t offset;
    uint16_t segment;
    uint64_t sec_id;
} ldap;

//uint16_t x __attribute__((aligned(4096)));

void kkk()
{
    ldap.size = 16;
    ldap.pad = 0;
    //x = 16;
}
```

After compiling it with -O2, -O3 or -Ofast, it will be :

```
    .globl  kkk
    .type   kkk, @function
kkk:
    movzwl  .LC0(%rip), %eax
    movw    %ax, ldap(%rip)
    ret
    .size   kkk, .-kkk
    .section    .rodata.cst2,"aM",@progbits,2
    .align 2
.LC0:
    .byte   16
    .byte   0
```

I think the best is :

```
kkk:
    movw    $16, ldap(%rip)
    ret
```

and this is also OK:

```
kkk:
    movl    $16, %eax
    movw    %ax, ldap(%rip)
    ret
```

But I really don't know what `rodata .LC0` does?

I'm using GCC 12.2 as the compiler, installed by apt on Ubuntu 22.10.

Comment: Is _what_ a missed optimization? What should be optimized?

Comment: I think a single instruction `movw    $16, ldap(%rip)` is OK. Why it need to add one more memory read？ @JohnFilleau

Comment: It's avoiding [LCP stalls](//stackoverflow.com/q/65530097) for 16-bit immediates, but those don't exist for `mov` on Sandybridge and later so it should stop doing that for tune=generic :P Also, it's insane that it's loading a `16` from the `.rodata` section instead of using it as an immediate.  The `movzwl` load with a RIP-relative addressing mode is already as large as `mov $16, %eax`.  Earlier GCC did do that, like GCC11 and earlier (https://godbolt.org/z/7qrafWhqd), so that's a GCC12 regression you should report on https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Near duplicate, I thought I'd already answered this but didn't find the Q&A right away: *[Why does the short (16-bit) variable mov a value to a register and store that, unlike other widths?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70719114/why-does-the-short-16-bit-variable-mov-a-value-to-a-register-and-store-that-u)*

This question also has a separate missed optimization when looking at the two 8-bit assignments, not one 16-bit integers.  Also, update: this GCC12 regression is already fixed in GCC trunk; sorry I forgot to check that before suggesting that you report it upstream.

---

It's avoiding [Length-Changing Prefix (LCP) stalls](//stackoverflow.com/q/65530097) for 16-bit immediates, but those don't exist for `mov` on Sandybridge and later so it should stop doing that for `tune=generic` :P  You're correct, `movw $16, ldap(%rip)` would be optimal.  That's what GCC uses when tuning for non-Intel uarches like `-mtune=znver3`.  Or at least what older versions did which didn't have the other missed optimization of loading from `.rodata`.

It's insane that it's loading a `16` from the `.rodata` section instead of using it as an immediate.  The `movzwl` load with a RIP-relative addressing mode is already as large as `mov $16, %eax`, so you're correct about that.  (`.rodata` is the section where GCC puts string literals, `const` variables whose address is taken or otherwise can't be optimized away, etc.  Also floating-point constants; loading a constant from memory is normal for FP/SIMD since x86 lacks a mov-immediate to XMM registers, but it's rare even for 8-byte integer constants.)

GCC11 and earlier did `mov $16, %eax` / `movw %ax, ldap(%rip)` (https://godbolt.org/z/7qrafWhqd), so that's a GCC12 regression you should report on https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla

---

Loading from `.rodata` doesn't happen with `x = 16` alone (https://godbolt.org/z/ffnjnxjWG). Presumably some interaction with coalescing two separate 8-bit stores into a 16-bit store trips up GCC.

```
uint16_t x __attribute__((aligned(4096)));
void store()
{
    //ldap.size = 16;
    //ldap.pad = 0;
    x = 16;
}
```

```
# gcc12 -O3 -mtune=znver3
store:
        movw    $16, x(%rip)
        ret
```

Or with the default tune=generic, GCC12 matches GCC11 code-gen.

```
store:
        movl    $16, %eax
        movw    %ax, x(%rip)
        ret
```

This is optimal for Core 2 through Nehalem (Intel P6-family CPUs that support 64-bit mode, which is necessary for them to be running this code in the first place.)  Those are obsolete enough that it's maybe time for current GCC to stop spending extra code-size and instructions and just mov-immediate to memory, since `mov imm16` opcodes specifically get special support in the pre-decoders to avoid an LCP stall, where there would be one with `add $1234, x(%rip)`.  See https://agner.org/optimize/, specifically his microarch PDF.     (`add sign_extended_imm8` exists, `mov` unfortunately doesn't, so `add $16, %ax` [wouldn't cause a problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37611247/x86-instruction-encoding-how-to-choose-opcode), but `$1234` would.)

But since those old CPUs don't have a uop cache, an LCP stall in an inner loop could make things *much* slower in the worst case.  So it's maybe worth making somewhat slower code for all modern CPUs in order to avoid that big pothole on the slowest CPUs.

Unfortunately GCC doesn't know that SnB fixed LCP stalls on `mov`: `-O3 -march=haswell` still does a 32-bit `mov`-immediate to a register first.  So `-march=native` on modern Intel CPUs will still make slower code :/

`-O3 -march=alderlake` does use mov-imm16; perhaps they updated the tuning for it because it also has E-cores which are silvermont-family.

Comment: Thanks you very much. I will report a bug to GCC.

Comment: GCC Bug created: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=108441

Comment: Maybe you can report a new bug, take a look at the latest comments: [link](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=108441#c5) . If you report a new bug, can you add me to the CC list? I'd like to see it too, thanks very much.